# React: How to change the state of a variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I've queried some data from Firebase realtime database and now I'm trying to add it to a variable. I'm sure that the querying works, because if I console.log(dataSnapshot) it logs the correct data (which is 001). However, when I'm trying to create a variable out of that number it doesn't return anything.

Here is a part of my code:

```
class Table extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { timestamps: [], user: auth().currentUser, serial: "" };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const uid = this.state.user.uid;
    console.log(uid);
    const serial = this.state.serial;
    const serialRef = db.ref(uid + "/serial");
    serialRef.once("value").then(function (dataSnapshot) {
      console.log(dataSnapshot.val());
      this.setState({ serial: dataSnapshot.val() });
    });
    console.log(serial);
```

[Here is a screenshot of my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpaSK.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What variable are you trying to set? Your last `console.log` is logging `serial`, which you set to an empty string. It will also run before the completion of fetching the firebase data

Comment: `componentDidMount` is called once the component is mounted. Did you try passing a static value like `this.setState({ serial: '001 });` instead of `this.setState({ serial: dataSnapshot.val() });`?

Comment: I'm trying to set the variable serial. I thought this changed it's state from an empty string: this.setState({ serial: dataSnapshot.val() });

Comment: @assembler I need to query different data from different users that's why I'm not passing a static value.

Comment: That does change the state but it does not change the value of the `serial` variable. It changes the value of `this.state.serial`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are logging your state variable serial to the console **before** its value is getting changed(asynchronous behaviour). Hence you are getting your serial variable as the original one.
If you wish to console.log your state variable serial in another variable immediately after setState then do the following:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const uid = this.state.user.uid;
    console.log(uid);
    let serial = this.state.serial;
    const serialRef = db.ref(uid + "/serial");
    serialRef.once("value").then(function (dataSnapshot) {
      console.log(dataSnapshot.val());
      this.setState({ serial: dataSnapshot.val() }, () => {
          serial = this.state.serial 
          console.log(serial)
        });
      });
    })
}
```

setState accepts a callback as an optional second parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This solved the problem, however, the variable is only saved in this function. Is there a way for the variable to used later in the code?

Comment: You can directly use your this.state.serial whenever required. Why use another variable. Your state is accesible throughout your component and you can pass it down as props too.